# How can I read image from Stream with ImageMagick.Net library

Tags: .net, imagemagick, filestream

I have a stream that has a picture. I need to write this picture to disk with a name in the format: "width x height".

The problem that I'm getting the picture dimensions with [ImageMagick](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/). but ImageMagick cannot read files from the memory, but only from the disk.

Is the only solution is to create a temp file, read it, and write another one?

Is their any better solution?

**Edit:** [this](http://midimick.com/magicknet/) project do support using streams, but it's older them [ImageMagick.net](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/) and have another drawbacks.